# Javascript Math.sin adding extra properties

Tags: javascript

How would I change Math.sin() so that if the user give Math.sin(angle, 'char')
it will take the sin in degree instead of radian.

So far I have

```
Math.sin= function()
{
    if(arguments.length>1)
    {
        return Math.sin(arguments[0]*(Math.PI/180));
    }
    else
    {
        return Math.sin(arguments[0]);
    }
};
```

but now I have infinite recursion so I assume we need a reference.
How would I go on finishing this?

Comment: Why don't you just create a new function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do that you'll need to keep a reference to the old version and call that:

```
var oldSin = Math.sin;

Math.sin= function()
{
    if(arguments.length>1)
    {
        return oldSin(arguments[0]*(Math.PI/180));
    }
    else
    {
        return oldSin(arguments[0]);
    }
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WQ9C9/

Your current code calls your new `Math.sin` infinitely (as you've discovered).

Answer (score 1):

Why not:

```
Math.mySin = function()
{
    if(arguments.length>1)
    {
        return Math.sin(arguments[0]*(Math.PI/180));
    }
    else
    {
        return Math.sin(arguments[0]);
    }
};
```